# Python Beginner: List index out of range error. Dice Roll

Tags: python

I'm a beginner in Python. I Was doing a dice rolling exercise question but I can't print the result of the sixth side of the dice. Can anyone teach me how to fix this code?

[screenshot of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F88hM.png)

[screenshot of code cont'd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FsZCO.png)

Comment: Please post your code as formatted text, instead of as image links.

Comment: Thanks Thomas. First time using Stackflow, I will do so next time.

Comment: It's easy enough to copy-paste your text into your question, why not do it now instead of next time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python the indexing from left to right starts at 0 and not 1. The indexes for the list therefore are 0,1,2,3,4,5  and not  1,2,3,4,5,6, 
so to get the no of times for

side 1  you will do
diceroll_results[0]

and for the 6th side you will do 
diceroll_results[5]

Hope this helps. :)

Answer (score 0):

The `diceroll _results` is a list - and a list is indexed from 0 (in Your case from 0 to 5)

So what Your code does is printing results from sides 2 to 6, and trying to print result from nonexistent`Side_7`

Comment: To show your gratitude would you consider properly formatting your question so other people can benefit from it - also you can accept the answer by clicking the green tick?